# Eclipse: The eclipse launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, desktop, launcher

I am running Debian 9 (new to it) and I have the following issue:

I have installed Eclipse (2019-09) and if am in the directory /opt/eclipse/java-2019-09/eclipse and enter `./eclipse` then Eclipse starts and everything is fine. Now, I created a Desktop Launcher which I can see in the Acvities section in Gnome, and if I click on it, I get

`The eclipse launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library`

My `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` has the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/opt/eclipse/java-2019-09/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/opt/eclipse/java-2019-09/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

So my question is how can I fix this respectively what it means if I launch Eclipse with `./eclipse` instead of `eclipse.`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the companion eclipse_xxxx.so file is located under <eclipse home>/plugins/<launcher plugin folder>. I suspect problem with working directory.

Can you try path parameter(pointing to eclipse install location) as described in https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#value-types